# Unable to run the Visual Studio 2013 SDK on Windows 10 : Windows Program Compatibility mode is on

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sdk, windows-10, development-environment

I wanted to share my experience of troubleshooting the problem I encountered when attempting to install Visual Studio 2013 SDK.

I downloaded the SDK from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013SDK.

I downloaded the installation to my Windows 10 machine and ran it and received the following error:

```
Setup Blocked : Windows Program Compatibility mode is on. Turn it off and then try again.
```

[image: Setup Blocked : Windows Program Compatibility mode is on. Turn it off and then try again.]

After a bit of searching I found that the issue is that the filename is different to the filename that the installation is expecting. I noticed this by running the installation in administrator mode which reported the actual file name. I updated the file name from `en_visual_studio_2013_sdk_x86_3009047.exe` to `vssdk_full.exe,` reran the installation and it installed successfully! :(

I am not sure why this is required so any suggestions welcome but wanted to share my experience for anyone else out there that may also be left scratching their heads.

Comment: don't answer your own question in the question itself. Post your own answer with the steps you did. Maybe Microsoft turned app compatibility for this SDK on because they saw issues with it. we can't answer this.

Comment: This is crazy. Thank you.